# I need to Update one record in mongodb?

Tags: node.js

```
router.patch('/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {
    
        try {
            let id = req.params.id;
            let updateData = req.body;
            const result = await Category.updateOne(id,updateData);
            if(result) {
                res.status(200).send({
                    result: result
                });
            }
        } 
        catch (err) {
            for (field in ex.errors) {
                res.status(500).send(ex.errors[field].message);            
            }
        }
    
})
```

This is my code but its not Working data not changed in records when i call this function

Comment: Are your ids strings? If not do you hace anything that converts the query id to ObjectID?

Comment: You need to specify a "filter" not just supply an id and hope that mongodb can figure out what you mean.  Try `{"_id": ObjectId(req.params.id)}`